# Typescript idiom to prevent duplicate modules included in a page

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have a TypeScript module defined like:

```
module Foo {
    export var now = new Date();
}
```

This gets transpiled to:

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    Foo.now = new Date();
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

If I were writing in pure JavaScript, I would have included something like:

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    if (window.Foo) return; // <-- PREVENT DUPLICATES!
    Foo.now = new Date();
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

to ensure that this module gets defined only once even if the `<script/>` gets included multiple times in a page. How do I achieve the same effect in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this discussion](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/542113) on TS forums, I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
module window {
    if (window.Foo) return;

    export module Foo {
        export var now = new Date()
    }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
var window;
(function (window) {
    if (window.Foo)
        return;

    (function (Foo) {
        Foo.now = new Date();
    })(window.Foo || (window.Foo = {}));
    var Foo = window.Foo;
})(window || (window = {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing your whole program in TypeScript, the compiler checks this for you...

```
module Foo {
    export class X {
        go() {
            alert('First');
        }
    }
}

module Foo {
    export class X { // Duplicate identifier X
        go() {
            alert('Second');
        }
    }
}
```

If you can, using external modules along with a module loader (RequireJS for example) ensures that non of your code needs to be added to the global scope, so it wouldn't conflict...

```
import foo = require('./foo');

export class Y {
    go() {
        return new foo.X();
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
define(["require", "exports", './foo'], function(require, exports, foo) {
    var Y = (function () {
        function Y() {
        }
        Y.prototype.go = function () {
            return new foo.X();
        };
        return Y;
    })();
    exports.Y = Y;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! My JS code is a library, which is to be included into HTML pages by page authors. So, both these solutions won't work for me.

Comment: Solutions 3 and 4 are... 3) Give it a unique name and tell users to treat it like a reserved work. 4) Don't use the module syntax, use the `(function (Foo) { /* ... */ }());` syntax - you can still add type annotations even though it isn't a module.

Comment: I found a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23120847/3973) for this. It is a tad hacky, but seems to work.